# Unable to load JSON

Tags: python, json

I have the code

```
data = open('wg.json', 'r').read()
data_parsed = json.loads(data)
```

And have received the error: `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`

With my JSON file being a python dictionary put into a json file:

```
{"wind_degrees":103, "dew_p": "73 F (23 C)", "wind_kph": 5.8}
```

Comment: In the future, you may find a JSON Linter helpful to catch these things: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: In the future, you should use a json validator tool to avoid json syntax errors.
Like : https://jsonlint.com

Comment: With your code and your amended json contents, I can run your code without issue.  I suggest that there is another error with your json file. (why did you type it in? what happened to copy/paste?)  on-hold reason still holds, as it can't be reproduced...

Comment: @Vyko @ Rome_Leader I have validated my updated, correct JSON and there were no issues with it

Comment: @Baldrickk I validated my entire file with the website suggested by Vyko and Rome_Leader

Comment: reopened it, better to check before pressing submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat wg.json
{"wind_degrees":103, "dew_p": "73 F (23 C)", "wind_kph": 5.8}
$python
>>> import json
>>> data = open('wg.json', 'r').read()
>>> data_parsed = json.loads(data)
>>> data_parsed
{u'wind_degrees': 103, u'wind_kph': 5.8, u'dew_p': u'73 F (23 C)'}
>>>
```

I can't reproduce your problem.  Your code works fine.

Note that you can streamline your code a little:

```
with open('wg.json', 'r') as fp:
    data_parsed = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: Turns out it had to do with the function I was trying to call the loads function in.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `"` after `73 F (23 C)` make that this way:

```
{"wind_degrees":103, "dew_p": "73 F (23 C)", "wind_kph": 5.8}
```

Comment: Sorry that was typo